# Not possible to click a Button

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

I'm having a weird issue with a button that is being shown on screen, but that I can't click. It is not that the `onClick` event is not firing, it seems that physically it does not react to clicks, as if it had a transparent layer on top of it.

The main `Activity` where it is built on:

```
public class MusicList extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
...
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);     

        setContentView(R.layout.mymusic);
        this.myTabHost = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.id.th_set_menu_tabhost); 
        this.myTabHost.setup(); 

        TabSpec ts = myTabHost.newTabSpec("TAB_TAG_1");

        ts.setIndicator("Media Item",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.music));             

        ts.setContent(R.id.media_item_tab);

        try {
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) myTabHost.findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent).findViewById(R.id.media_item_tab);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"Layout is not correct",e);
        }

            Button button = (Button)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
            // button.setClickable(true);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
                    myTabHost.addTab(ts);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(itemData.get("ITEM_URL"))));
    }
}
```

The layout, which is shown perfect on screen is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:id="@+id/th_set_menu_tabhost" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
     <TabWidget 
          android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
     <FrameLayout 
          android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:paddingTop="65px">

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/media_item_tab"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/media_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#40A5D9"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:text="Title"
                >
                </TextView>
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/media_cover"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="180px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/media_title"
                android:src="@drawable/geniocover"              
                >
                </ImageView>
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/media_author"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#86CCF3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:layout_below="@+id/media_cover" 
                android:text="Author"
                >
                </TextView>
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/media_album"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#DAFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:layout_below="@+id/media_author"    
                android:text="Album (Year)"
                >
                </TextView>
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/play_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Play"
                android:textColor="#003983"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/media_album"
                android:clickable="true"    
                >
                </Button>
            </RelativeLayout>
          <ListView
          android:id = "@+id/tablist"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          /> 
     </FrameLayout> 
</TabHost>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I am curious: why do you use a RelativeLayout when all elements are below the previous - a LinearLayout with orientation=vertical could do as well?

Comment: Well, the current layout is simply a mockup we are working on, so it has suffered several changes from its first state (when it was indeed a RelativeLayout). I will try to change this in order to rule out this as the source of the problem.

Comment: You say *It is not that the onClick event is not firing*, but I see in a comment you also say *it never enters it*. I'm confused.

Comment: What I meant is that the problem is a prior one: the button is not clickable, not in the sense that it is marked as clickable=false, but as if it was impossible for that Tab to focus. The scope of that comment was that it was obviously not an issue with view id check inside the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `FrameLayout` with two children when it's only intended to host one.  The `ListView` was last added, will end up on top and is probably receiving all of your input.

Comment: It worked! It is a bit awkward imho that the order in the layout xml is taken into account, but it solved my problem anyway :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the complex structure of your tablayout.

Usually, I use a separate Activity holding the TabLayout and just put different activities as content into the tabhost (`tabSpec.setContent(Intent intent)`).

Actually this should solve your problem.

By the way, avoid using `RelativeLayout` where you could use a LinearLayout.

Comment: Both methods for are valid for Tab building, so I don't think moving from same Activity for multiple tabs to one Activity per tab is the proper solution. It would probably solve it, but it is possible to do this with one single Activity.